# .replace not working on \n in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Javascript string that ends in `\n` and I want to remove the last instance of `\n` through only regex. So I wrote this query `/..$/` which targets it. However, when I run `string1.replace(/..$/, "")` the `.replace` still returns the original string and does not replace the last instance of `\n` with an empty string.

How can I use regex to remove those last two characters?

I've tried this

```
let string1 = '0,1,2,3,45\n10,11,12,13,14\n20,21,22,23,24\n30,31,32,33,34\n'

string1.replace(/..$/, "") 

=> '0,1,2,3,45\n10,11,12,13,14\n20,21,22,23,24\n30,31,32,33,34\n'
```

Comment: Do you *have to* use regex? Because you can just check the last character of the string and remove it if it's a new line, otherwise.

Comment: yes, i know it's a cumbersome way of doing this, but it has to be regex.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure you assign the result to a variable? Also, `.` does not match `\n`. You need to use `[\s\S]` to match any char including a newline.

Comment: (/..$/) matches the last two characters in the string

Comment: @Dog yes, but dot doesn't always match everything. Also, `\n` is not two characters but a single one.

Comment: in rubular that Regex combo matches it

Comment: Use only one `.` and add the modifier `s`: `/.$/s`

Comment: i get an invalid regex expression error with that combo and it doesn't work in rubular. the /..$/ regex expression is the only one that works in rubular.

Comment: @Jordão `s` is not a valid flag in JS

Comment: This also doesn't work [\s\S]. it's invalid.

Comment: @Dog and @vlaz: it actually works on the Chrome console. Try it: `string1.replace(/.$/s, "")`

Comment: why is that /s necessary?

Comment: I suppose the default is a multi-line match, and the `s` treats the whole string as one line (`s` stands for single-line)

Comment: @Jordão it's not an official thing - doesn't work in Firefox and it's not even listed as an option on MDN.

Comment: @vlaz you're right! Thanks for spotting that. It only works on Chrome then. Use at your own risk. How sad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked in the console for me:

```
string1.replace(/\n$/,"");
```

Comment: That works. Rubular must recognize \n as characters so ..$ works there, but in console they aren't recognized and need to be specifically identified as \n. Thank you.